# How to send POST request in python 3?

Tags: python, python-requests

This is how my code looks like. I need to find out how can make call since I am new to Python.

```
         HEADER = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x'
    }

    BODY = {
        'scope': 'b2b',
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': var_clientid,
        'client_secret': var_clientsecret
    }
```

Comment: 1. Why do you think you need other "imports functions"; have you had specific problems using `requests`? Give a [mcve]. 2. Why does it matter how many files you use, have you had any particular issue with how many you have now? 3. No.

Comment: Well I initially replied stating I just started programming so I am not sure 90% of stuff.  so I am not even sure what `requests` and etc on other questions you asked.

Based on my input. you think you can help me make GET call to 1 of the API end point URL in just general programming with Python 3.7?

I know I might not be making much sense I am learning how to ask questions and such...

Comment: Then see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html, http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ and [ask].

Comment: add more information to your question, please read the guidelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to connect!

```
import requests

url = 'someurlexample'

BODY = {
    'scope': 'b2b',
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': var_clientid,
    'client_secret': var_clientsecret
}

S = requests.session()
post = S.post(url, data=BODY, json=False)
```